# MKMapView NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Maybe this question is already asked, but i couldnt find it. The error i get is really giving me a headache!

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MapViewController 0x8095670> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapView.'
```

I think this is when the annotation is setted and the event is called. My code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceMark class]]) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = 
    (MKPinAnnotationView *)[myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                          initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    // Create a UIButton object to add on the 
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

    UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    [leftButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [annotationView setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:leftButton];

    return annotationView;
}

return nil; 
}
```

I'm a bit a newbie to ObjC. But if you need any code for more inspection i'll be pleased to send it you!

Comment: Check that the IBOutlets in the MapViewController xib are all connected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see it in the code you've shown, but have you tried to set mapview on your controller somewhere but not set it up as a property? Maybe you used the wrong name in the declaration and you're calling `viewcontroller.mapView = ....`